# Where is the instance of "IntConverter" stored?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Let's suppose we have the following program:

```
public class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> converters = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object[], object>>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         RegisterImplementation(new IntConverter());
         int value = (int) dic[typeof(int)]("4");
         Console.WriteLine(value); //Prints 4
    }

    private static RegisterImplementation<X>(IConverter<X> converter)
    {
         Type type = typeof(X);
         Func<object, object> conversion = (obj) => converter.Convert(obj);
         if(dic.ContainsKey(type))
             dic[type] = conversion;
         else
             dic.Add(type, conversion);
    }
}

public interface IConverter<X>
{
    X Convert(object obj);
}

public class IntConverter : IConverter<int>
{
    public int Convert(object obj)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(obj);
    }
}
```

I understand most of the code, but the part that's driving me mad is the `RegisterImplementation` method. In the dictionary we are storing a `Func<object, object>` instance, and the `converter` is not stored anywhere, so I am assuming we lose the local reference when we get out of the method.

So how can we call the function in the dictionary afterwards and use this reference of `IntConverter`? Where is it stored? Inside the `Func<object, object>`?

Comment: See [Lambda Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and especially the section "Variable Scope in Lambda Expressions": "Variables that are captured in this manner are stored for use in the lambda expression even if the variables would otherwise go out of scope"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it's worth being clear that your question doesn't actually involve expression trees at all - your lambda expression is just being converted into a delegate.

Now, that lambda expression is this:

```
(obj) => converter.Convert(obj)
```

That *captures* the local variable, `converter`. In practice, that means the C# compiler will have created a new class, like this:

```
private class UnspeakableName<X>
{
    public IConverter<X> converter;

    public object Method(object obj)
    {
        return converter(obj);
    }
}
```

Then your method will be converted into:

```
private static RegisterImplementation<X>(IConverter<X> converter)
{
     UnspeakableName<X> tmp = new UnspeakableName<X>();
     tmp.converter = converter;

     Type type = typeof(X);
     Func<object, object> conversion = tmp.Method;
     if(dic.ContainsKey(type))
         dic[type] = conversion;
     else
         dic.Add(type, conversion);
}
```

So the target of the delegate will be the instance of the new class, and *that* keeps the converter alive.

Comment: Does anyone else feel the need to read one of Jon's [books](http://www.amazon.com/Jon-Skeet/e/B001JP0M8K)?

Comment: Thank you for the perfectly explained answer

Answer (score 1):

The lambda code `(obj) => converter.Convert(obj)` uses the local `converter`. The local is kept alive by this lambda code.